# Translate android app made by Adobe Air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, translation

After further researches, I found that for making android apps with AIR technologies, it requires AIR runtime on the android device, and Flash professional CS5, then, youn can  publish your flash project under apk extension, even install it as an android application automatically after publishing it, if you are connecting your device via usb cable, and you are already installed the sdk tools with the usb connector package if you're on windows.

So all of this is great, but, I only have the apk extension of the app, with a file called main.swf, i want to know  that if I use the Flash professional cs5 to open the main.swf file, will I be able to modify fields labels for example, and then translate the labels from english to french ?. if not, what is the right way to translate an app made  by Flash, when you only have the apk decompiled of the application containing the swf file ?

Thank you for your answers, i'm here if you need any further explainaitions about my situation.

Comment: Short answer is no. If you don't have access to the source code, your best bet is to use one of the various Flash decompilers and attempt to rebuild from that.

Comment: So i have to decompile the main.swf file, modify source code, and compile it again ? can you advice me best tools doing that ( decompiling and compiling ) ?